# Error with mpi_comm_split in fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have some questions on `mpi_comm_split` in Fortran.

Question I)
How can I create a single one communicator with `mpi_comm_split`? For example, I want to create a communicator based only on processors which are on the top of my domain (Cartesian). I know that I have to use `MPI_UNDEFINED` for process that I don't want to be part of my new communicator, but my code below didn't make want I expect.

```
do k=1,size(proc_up)
if(rank==proc_up(k)) then
color_up=1
else 
color_up=MPI_UNDEFINED
end if
call MPI_COMM_SPLIT(comm2d ,color_up ,coords(2) ,comm_up ,code)
```

Why it didn't work?

Question II)

When I want to make several `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` (new comm for up, down, side1, side2), it returns an error:

```
[nin:30039] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_split
[nin:30039] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[nin:30039] *** MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
[nin:30039] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

Does anyone know why?

QUESTION III)

I can also use `MPI_Cart_sub`, but it will returns me many groups of process. How to be sure to use only the group I just want?

Comment: In Q1 where is the End Do for the loop? Q2 please show the code - in general it makes it much easier for us to help if you show a small but complete program that illustrates the problem you are having. For Q3 MPI_CART_SUB "chops up" the cartesian into lower dimensionality objects, for instance a cube can be cut into planes. The communicator resulting on a given process contains all processes in the chosen plane.

Comment: Please make your questions answerable in a single answer. For example ask about your crash only and then about Cartesian communicators in a different question. Be sure to show your code. Read the help section to find out how to ask here.

Comment: ok I am new here so I didn't know yet how to manage (I will read the help section).
For the question I) indeed I forget the end do (juste before the split).
So for question I) did you have an idea why It don't work?

Comment: What's the content of proc_up? You would need it to be the local rank from some point onwards, if it is the local rank in just one place and subsequent entries are not, you would overwrite color_up with MPI_UNDEFINED again. Is this what you want? We can't know what you want, so you need to more clearly describe what you use as input  and what you expect as output.